# Prestashop - add a custom menu item for my module under admin menu

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

My question is :

How can I add, by code, a custom menu item for my prestashop module under the orders menu (for example) in the pestashop backoffice ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a menu item on module install function.

```
$currentid = Tab::getIdFromClassName('YOUR_ADMINCLASS');
if (!$currentid ) {
  $tab = new Tab();
  $tab->active = 1;
  $tab->class_name = "YOUR_ADMINCLASS";
  $tab->name = array();
  foreach (Language::getLanguages() as $lang){
    $tab->name[$lang['id_lang']] = "DISPLAYNAME";
  }
  $tab->id_parent = $parentTabid;
  $tab->module = $this->name;
  $tab->add();
}
```

To place as submenu or Orders, search for the `$parentTabid`:

```
$sql = "SELECT `id_tab` FROM `"._DB_PREFIX_."tab` WHERE `class_name` LIKE 'AdminParentOrders'";
$parentTabid = Db::getInstance()->getValue($sql);
```

Comment: worked for me. Thanks